# Webpack: Custom loader and plugin order

Tags: typescript, webpack, uglifyjs, babel-loader

I'm new to webpack 4 and I am wondering how to set a specific order for my loaders and plugins.

Actually I want to bundle a ES6 typescript project to ES5 and minifying it for production use including property names. For that I defined the following loader:

```
{
    test: /\.ts?$/,
    include: paths.appSrc,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [{
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
                transpileOnly: true,
                configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, "./tsconfig.prod.json")
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And I'm using the uglifyjs webpack plugin for minifying the code

```
optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            uglifyOptions: {...},
            sourceMap: true
        })
    ]
}
```

So the process for this configuration is

1. ts-loader: Typescript (ES6) --> Javascript (ES6)
2. babel-loader:
   Javascript (ES6) --> Javascript (ES5)
3. uglifyjs: minify the
   Javascript (ES5)

The babel-loader creates this function in step 2)

```
function _createClass(Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
  if (protoProps) _defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);
  if (staticProps) _defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps);
  return Constructor;
}
```

And using it like this

```
_createClass(myComponent, [{
      key: "AddElement",
      value: function AddElement() {
        var element = document.createElement("div");
        element.innerHTML = "Hello webpack";
        document.body.appendChild(element);
      }
}]);
```

The code represents in ES5 a ES6 class called "myComponent" with the function called "AddElement". The problem is that the function name is setted as a string and uglifyjs is not able to recognize this name. So when I configure uglifyjs to mangle property names too the code will fail.

Now I thought that maybe I could change the loader/plugin order. If the order would be like this there wouldn't be a problem

1. ts-loader
2. uglifyjs
3. babel-loader

**Is it possible to set a custom order for loaders and plugins in webpack 4?**

Comment: this could help you: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/140 (but didn't work for me though.)